# Camera on Lockscreen

Tags: lock-screens, default-applications, google-camera, xiaomi-pocophone-f1

I have a Poco F1 running Miui. The Gcam is a much better camera than the stock one. Is there a way for me to change the camera that is opened on the lockscreen?

Comment: GravityBox xposed module has the option  to tweak that but I am not sure the module would work on a heavily modified skin such as of MiUi

Comment: That would require root wouldn't it. I do agree that Miui is heavily modified so maybe there isn't a way.

Comment: Yes, that requires root and Xposed framework. That said, you can try a third-party lock screen app which provides an option to tweak which app shortcut to be shown on the lock screen.